# single instance in MediatR and NInject

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, mediatr

In the bootstrap of my app (MVC with NInject) I bind these two requests to my service:

```
  kernel.Bind <IRequestHandler<SaveItemrequest, int>>()
       .To<MyService>();
kernel.Bind <IRequestHandler<MyGetmessageRequest, List<string>>>()
       .To<MyService>();


        kernel.Bind<SingleInstanceFactory>().ToMethod(ctx => t => ctx.Kernel.TryGet(t));
        kernel.Bind<MultiInstanceFactory>().ToMethod(ctx => t => ctx.Kernel.GetAll(t));
             kernel.Bind<IMediator>().To<Mediator>();
```

in the service, I have

```
public int Handle(SaveItemrequest req){
    int id= _db.save(req.Item);
    this.messages.add("OK");
   return id;
}
public List<string> Handle(MyGetmessageRequest req){

   return this.messages;
}
```

but since MediatR creates a new instance of `MyService` when I get back my messages the list is empty:

```
id=_mediatr.Send(_saveReq); //ok
msgs=mediatr.Send(_getMsgsreq); //always empty
```

Is there any way to force MediatR to use the same instance for every request?

Comment: Deleted my answer for now as I mis-read your `messages` collection - Could you store those in the DB? And return them from there?

Comment: If you could elaborate on what the purpose of `messages` is, I have another idea that could solve this

Comment: thanks. Messages is a collection of strings that is populated by the service methods. It is populated incrementally as outcomes of operations, errors, warnigs. after all the operations have been made on the service, the controller needs all the messages to display them on the view.

Comment: thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design - you're going against the CQS pattern trying to do what you're suggesting. Command Query *Separation*. Your handler shouldn't maintain state.

However, what you could do, is have another service, with 'per request' lifetime scope, that contains the list of messages for that request.
This is more appropriate than a true singleton - as a singleton will have ALL messages, for ALL requests (across users etc...)

Firstly, create a wrapper around a `List<string>` that could look like this:

```
public interface IMessageStore
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetMessages();
    void AddMessage(string message);
}

public class MessageStore : IMessageStore
{
    private List<string> _messages = new List<string>();

    public IEnumerable<string> GetMessages()
    {
        return _messages.ToList();
    }

    public void AddMessage(string message)
    {
        _messages.Add(message);
    }
}
```

Then, configure this in NInject to be [InRequestScope](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope)

```
kernel.Bind<IMessageStore>>().To<MessageStore>()
    .InRequestScope();
```

This will keep the instance of `MessageStore` around for the request.

In your handler, take a dependency on `IMessageStore`

```
public class MyService : <IRequestHandler<SaveItemrequest, int>, IRequestHandler<MyGetmessageRequest, List<string>>
{
    public MyService(IMessageStore messageStore)
    {
        _messageStore = messageStore;
    }

    public int Handle(SaveItemrequest req)
    {
        int id= _db.save(req.Item);

        _messageStore.AddMessage("OK");

        return id;
    }

    public List<string> Handle(MyGetmessageRequest req){

       return _messageStore.GetMessages();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I've done in a similar way, I elaborate on a separate answer. I'm accepting your answer, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have done in a way similar as what @Alex proposed. I have created an `HandlerService` service that implements the Handle functions above, I inject `MyService` in it with scope to the httpcontext lifecycle:

`kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>().InScope(ctx => HttpContext.Current ?? StandardScopeCallbacks.Thread(ctx));` ;

and I bind

```
 kernel.Bind <IRequestHandler<SaveItemrequest, int>>()
       .To<HandlerService>();
kernel.Bind <IRequestHandler<MyGetmessageRequest, List<string>>>()
       .To<HandlerService>();
```

now my Handler service has a reference to MyService that spawns the life of the HttpRequest. the Handler Service is instantiated for each request but the MyService reference it uses it is not, so the Messages collection is preserved and can be queried later.
Thanks.